# Why is a query with aggregates returning a result when it has a false predicate? Is there a way to not get a result?

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

Why does this query return a result set?

SELECT SomeString = 'Total'
,SUM(1)
WHERE 1 = 2

I have a similar query that since the predicate is false I was under the assumption that it shouldn't return a result. Is this intended? If so, how can I not have a result returned by the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate queries always return one row per group, and without a GROUP BY return one row.

If you don't want a row returned you can use a non-aggregate query like

```
SELECT SomeString = 'Total', 
       SUM(1) over() total
WHERE 1 = 2
```

or a subquery like

```
with q as 
(
    SELECT SomeString = 'Total', SUM(1) total
    WHERE 1 = 2
)
select *
from q
where total is not null
```